# How to make text and image side by side

Tags: html, css

So, I was planning to add the image and text to be side by side but every time I move the text it randomly disappears.
 Here's what it looks like:

[image]

```css
.profile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.profile img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 160px;
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile">
  <img src="https://icon-library.com/images/default-profile-icon/default-profile-icon-24.jpg" alt="profile">
  <h2>ASPECTER</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.list_view
{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}
.list_view h2
{
padding:10px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="list_view">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="profile">
     <h2>ASPECTER</h2>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap, It will be cleaner method

```
 <div classs="row"><div class="col-md-3"><img src="imgsource"></img></div>
<div class="col-md-9">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` properties to do so.

Give flex to the wrapping div and then align the child inside it as per your requirements

Below is the example

```css
.maindiv{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.profileimg {
    top: 10px;
    right: 160px;
    width: 40px;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 500px;
}
.text {
   margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
   <img class="profileimg" src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/pang/IHXoEES.png" alt="profile">
   <h2 class="text">ASPECTER</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: It suddenly vanished of the screen

Comment: What is vanishing? Just run the code snippet and try to implement in the same way

Answer (score 0):

using `flex` and `flex-wrap` css should work for you with reactivity even on smaller screens.

```css
.profile {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
```

`flex-grow` property can be used to achieve how much the item will grow relative to the rest of the flexible items.